# Convert sql Rows into Column using Pivot as shown below

Tags: sql, pivot-table, report, dml, time-and-attendance

I am looking to generate a report which is basically a attendance report using SQL query from table data rows; I have employee punch data as row in table with columns such as
PDate | EmpCode | EmpName | PStatus | OT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF8tW.png)

The above image shows the snap of data in table.

I am looking to generate the results as shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcYaV.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT [Name], [Value] FROM [dbo].[Table] ) AS SourceTable PIVOT ( MAX([Value]) FOR [Name] IN ( [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [Phone] ) ) AS PivotTable
```

I hope it will help you.